# Can anyone wonder why the variable is not being processed by the select statement as i intend it to?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a dynamic sql select statement that receives an input   from a $_post and uses the value from the post method to be used in the select statement. This will produce a result of emails based of off the  input the user enters in the $_post method. e.g if they enter in yahoo,  yahoo gets passed through the post and then gets placed into the sql 
statement.

This is the code that i would need in my sql statement where $var is the 
variable the user inputs.

select * FROM ioncubedata where emailaddress LIKE "% @ $var %" so that 
    any data the user inputs will be placed where $var is.

```
<?php
$_POST['rain'];
$name = $_POST['rain'];
$rainName = SQLite3::escapeString($name);
$db = new SQLite3('mydb.sq3');
$sql = "select * FROM `slalom` where `emailaddress` LIKE  "%@." 
".$domainName." ".%" ";
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

error messages from my ways of manipulating the $rainName variable are;
-unexpected '$rainName' variable
- nothing (empty screen)
- or syntax errors such as (unexpected "'")

Comment: your syntax for `$sql` is wrong, it should be: `$sql = "select * FROM ioncubedata where emailaddress LIKE  '%@$domainName'";`

Comment: you sir Mr tim, has saved me hours of stress. Thank you.